# Notepad++ Combine 2 texts line after line

Tags: regex, notepad++, text-processing

I am trying to create a text file containing translation of two different languages. Specifically from Japanese to English. The appropriate format I have chosen is to have the Japanese text placed on the first line, then the translated English line to the next, and so forth.

Now lets say I have two text files named Japanese.txt and English.txt.

Japanese.txt contains the following:

```
Japanese Text Line 1
Japanese Text Line 2
Japanese Text Line 3
```

English.txt contains the translated Japanese text to English:

```
English Translation Line 1
English Translation Line 2
English Translation Line 3
```

What I want is to merge them in another file named Translation.txt that is in this format:

```
Japanese Text Line 1
English Translation Line 1
Japanese Text Line 2
English Translation Line 2
Japanese Text Line 3
English Translation Line 3
```

Comment: Have you tried any of the [ideas provided in the NP++ forum?](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/14965/combine-2-texts-line-by-line)

Comment: Thank you! This post did exactly as I wanted: https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/post/28924